# KSoap services how to send soap object data in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am new to KSoap,i followed many tutorials but not able to properly send this below soap object data, am using KSOAP2 (3.2 jar file),please find the below XML code which i need to send.I have already wasted more than a day, So please help me Thanks in advance.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ver:saveQuote>
        <quoteData>
            <lastModifiedDate nil="true" />
            <customerData>
                <customerBusinessName>Customer</customerBusinessName>
                <customerPhone>600</customerPhone>
                <customerFirstName>Customer</customerFirstName>
                <customerLastName>Ain</customerLastName>
                <customerAddr1>eve</customerAddr1>
                <customerAddr2>00</customerAddr2>
                <customerCity>apolis</customerCity>
                <customerCountry>S</customerCountry>
                <customerCounty>Hpin</customerCounty>
                <customerEmail>admm</customerEmail>
                <customerFax nil="true" />
                <customerState>M</customerState>
                <customerZipCode>55</customerZipCode>
                <customerCommLocID>0</customerCommLocID>
                <customerCommTypeID>0</customerCommTypeID>
                <customerCompEntityId nil="true" />
                <customerEntityId nil="true" />
                <customerBusinessPhoneNumber nil="true" />
                <customerHomePhoneNumber nil="true" />
            </customerData>
            <expirationDate>10/16/2013</expirationDate>
            <quoteName>T service</quoteName>
            <dealerId>x867</dealerId>
            </quoteData>
    </ver:saveQuote>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Post your code that you have tried so far. And you can use SoapUi tool to debug the api. http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: i want to know how to add request property for the above XML request.addProperty("KEY","VALUE");